# How to implement convolutional connections without tied weights?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Given two layers of a neural network that have a 2D representation, i.e. fields of activation. I'd like to connect each neuron of the lower layer to the near neurons of the upper layer, say within a certain radius. Is this possible with TensorFlow?

[image: Connection pattern]

This is similar to a convolution, but the weight kernels should not be tied. I'm trying to avoid connecting both layers fully first and masking out most of the parameters, in order to keep the number of parameters low.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a simple way to do this with existing TensorFlow ops efficiently, but there might be some tricks with sparse things. However, ops for efficient locally connected, non-convolutional neural net layers would be very useful, so you might want to file a feature request as a GitHub issue.